# How to expand your plot so all labels can be seen without overlapping in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

I have a plot with 50 categories(states) that show on my X axis, but in my output they are on top of each other. I want my plot to be spread out engough/large enough that there is no overlap and you could determine the state value from the next.
NOTE: i used the coord_flip command, so I know that my X-axis is actually my Y in image and vice versa. I am just wondering what function I would use to fix problem.

[image: Image of my output]

Comment: maybe try `theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 3))` and play with the value of size

Answer (score 2):

You can always change the size of the text via `themes(axis.text.x=element_text(size=...))`...

But the easy answer here is that your plot will change appearance based on the aspect ratio.  When you view in Rstudio, you can adjust the size of your plot and you'll see the rearrangement.  Additionally, when you save, the plot, play around in particular to the `height` and `width` to get the ratio you want.  `ggsave('filename.png', width=??, height=??)`.